# Entity Framework and Cast<>

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have this class (you can see it in its entirety [here](https://github.com/bmckenzie/projects/blob/development/Projects.DataAccess.Sql/Repositories/Base/BaseRepository.cs))...

```
internal class BaseRepository<I, C> : IRepository<I>
    where I : class, IBaseObject
    where C : BaseObject
{
    private Context _context;

    public IEnumerable<I> FindBy(Expression<Func<I, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _context.Set<C>().ToList().Cast<I>().AsQueryable().Where(predicate);
    }

    // other methods.
}
```

How can I work this so I don't have to call `.ToList()` which I believe causes EF to return everything in `.Set<C>()`

Using this without `.ToList()` and `.AsQueryable()` causes the error:

System.NotSupportedException: Unable to cast the type 'Sln.DAL.Sql.Entities.Project' to type 'Sln.DAL.Entities.IProject'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: Mind telling us why you need the `ToList`? What happens if you remove it?

Comment: Is BaseObject always derived from I?

Comment: Yes it is.  BaseObject implements IBaseObject

Comment: Phil, add your answer again. it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we add a constraint

```
internal class BaseRepository<I, C> : IRepository<I>
    where I : class, IBaseObject
    where C : BaseObject, I
```

Can we then use

```
_context.Set<C>().Where(predicate).AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: `context.Set<C>().Where(predicate).AsEnumerable();` throws an exception in linq2EF.